# How to return a value from a keyboard shortcut

Tags: applescript

sorry but I'm quite clueless about programming in general. I have this clipboard manager that allows me to recall x number of items in my clipboard history, for instance, if I hold down Command+Option+Shift+3, it will paste the 3rd most recent clipboard item. Using this, I am trying to return the value through an applescript in BetterTouchTools. I tried this:

```
tell application "System Events" to set tempclip to keystroke "3" using {option down, shift down, command down}
end tell
return tempclip
```

However, I am getting a syntax error. (let me remind you I don't know any programming xD). Could someone please help me with correcting this syntax. I'm very desperate :(
Thanks in advance. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a block like so:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set tempclip to keystroke "3" using {option down, shift down, command down}
end tell
```

or you can use a single-line command, like so:

```
tell application "System Events" to set tempclip to keystroke "3" using {option down, shift down, command down}
```

either will work, but what you did in your script was use a single-line command followed by an `end tell`, as though you were using a block. That's confusing the compiler.

Comment: Hi Ted, thank you so much. That totally makes sense now. :) 
I used the block format and followed it by "return tempclip" but I get the following error: 
error "The variable tempclip is not defined." number -2753 from "tempclip"

I tried defining the variable as global and/or set variable to "" and still the error persists. Is there anything wrong I'm doing here?

Comment: Hm. Well, I suspect the clipboard manager is pasting the 3rd most recent clip somewhere, but isn't actually returning anything to the AppleScript. Without knowing what clip manager you're using I can't say much more. You may have to paste the clip somewhere and then retrieve it for the AppleScript, or maybe there's a more direct way to get at it.